# Using custom bootstrap3 themes with Meteor.js

Tags: css, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootswatch

I've added bootstrap 3 to my meteorjs project according to the readme here:  https://github.com/mangasocial/meteor-bootstrap-3

Everything works great, but now I would like to theme my bootstrap with http://bootswatch.com/ (simplex) theme.  According to the directions I need to replace the default bootstrap CSS file with a downloaded one.  My questions what is the proper "meteor" way to accomplish this?  How do I override a file that is included as part of a meteor package?

Comment: You can always git clone the package in your project local packages directory and manually override the files by copying them in the local clone.

Comment: Ya I was worried I might need to do that.  I think that I would need to fork the project on github and then apply my changes.  But this would prevent me from getting future updates...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove the `bootstrap-3` package and put your custom bootstrap3 in your meteor project. For example:

```
PROJECT/
    client/
        css/
            bootstrap.css
        js/
            bootstrap.js
```

Comment: You can also fork the bootstrap3 repository, replace the bootstrap.css, and then publish it to meteorite. But I suggest put it in your project since it's a custom css file

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the `twbs:bootstrap` Bootstrap 3 meteor package.  I downloaded a new theme from [Bootswatch](http://bootswatch.com/) which is a bootstrap.min.css file, and tossing that file in my meteor project seems to have worked.  I think the CSS in the project is able to override the default Bootstrap CSS.